# Apache Nifi - Read data from multiple tables in a single flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I’m planning to use Apache Nifi for a Data Ingestion use case. The source could be flat files and `Teradata` database and the output sink would be `Oracle` database. I have created few flows to read data from flat files using `GetFile` and Teradata database using `ExecuteSQL` and load the data to Oracle database using `PutSQL`. Everything seems to be working fine. And we are forecasting that source system might change in future and I noticed that the processors are available in Nifi to support that sources.

Now my questions, is it possible to read more than one table from Teradata database and load the data in to multiple tables in oracle database in a single Nifi flow? I have built individual flows for each table and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Nifi are you using? If you are using [ExecuteSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html) for each table, and a recent version of NiFi  (1.0.0 and later) you could use the [ListDatabaseTables](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListDatabaseTables/index.html) processor, then a [ReplaceText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) to create a SQL statement to get the rows for that table (using [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)), then send that to ExecuteSQL to do the fetching, and whatever downstream processors you have to put the rows to Oracle table(s).